# Can't push to master branch in github

Tags: git, github

I've got a repo in github with `master` and `1.0` branches.

When I push changes from local repo to github to `1.0` branch, it's ok.

But when I push changes from local to github to `master` branch, it fails with message:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Unavailable
```

- I have no protected branches.
- I'm the github repo owner.
- origin looks like `https://user@github.com/user/repo.git`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changed origin to `https://github.com/user/repo.git` and it works.

Update. 
Looks it was github server bug.

Comment: I really don't think this was your problem. 503 server error usually means the service was temporarily unavailable usually due to high network traffic.

Comment: The only change is user name at start.  I don't know how it matters but it helped.

Comment: since your different branch pushes both specified the same remote, then I fail to see how it could make a difference. moreover, there are two similar questions, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488733/503-error-pushing-to-remote) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488659/git-push-fails-with-5kb-data) within 30 minutes of yours with the same problem, implying an issue with Github's servers

Comment: Ok, seems it's just a server bug. May be some maintenance works took place. Thanks for links.

Comment: although, I think it was still a good idea to change the url as you did because it looks like it was a mix between the https `https://github.com/user/repo.git` and the ssh `git@github.com:user/repo.git` version. I have confirmed that I can still clone using `https://user@github.com/user/repo.git`, but I'm not sure if that's standard or a special feature for github.

Comment: when we clone repo its by default takes https:// for the remote.