# error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503

Tags: git, github

I am facing below error when trying to commit code to https://github.com.

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 26, done.
Counting objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (26/26), 9.37 KiB | 799.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 26 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I already went thru link: [503 error pushing to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488733/503-error-pushing-to-remote). But still its not working and many people have faced this issue but no one has put confirmed answer on the same.

Its having because I am behind company firewall as before I was able to do it before?

Answer (score 9):

GitHub does not normally produce 503 errors, so this error you're getting is likely due to a machine somewhere in the middle.

You mentioned you're using a company firewall, which is likely the source of this problem.  Other possibilities are any sort of proxy or antivirus software.  Sometimes these programs think they find something malicious, offensive, or inappropriate in Git's compressed data and block it, or they require authentication and you haven't provided any.

The easiest way to try to figure this out is to complete uninstall any antivirus software other than Windows Defender (disabling it is often not enough) and move to another location that isn't restricted by a proxy or corporate firewall.  Then, reintroduce each one of these situations until the problem reoccurs.

If the problem is a proxy, you can set the `http_proxy` environment variable to refer to the URL to the proxy and Git will honor it.  If it's your corporate proxy or corporate-mandated antivirus, contact your company's IT department and inform them of the problem.

If all else fails, you can [view the documentation on the GitHub website](https://help.github.com/en/articles/troubleshooting-connectivity-problems) that links to the GitHub Debug portal to help you troubleshoot the problem further.

Comment: I am able to commit easily, but cant push it. Any work around ? As I cant disable the antivirus and corporate firewall.

Comment: Committing doesn't involve a network operation.  This is likely somewhere in your network, as mentioned.  You can try using https://github-debug.com/ to troubleshoot the problem, though.

Comment: I am facing same problem, I think this is due to company firewall that prevents to push anything to github.
I am not able to upload any file to Github from UI too.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of company firewall policies. It intersect upload call and quarantine it.
Ask your company IT admin to open firewall for you to push code to new repo